# Create a sub-mode of an existing mode which overrides certain functions?

Tags: major-mode, customize, functions, minor-mode

I want to make a few customizations to [cmake-model.el](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob_plain;hb=master;f=Auxiliary/cmake-mode.el). The big-picture view of this lisp file is as follows:

```
...

;; This function I want to modify
(defun cmake-indent ()
  ...
  )

...

;; Mode definition.
;;
;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode cmake-mode cmake--parent-mode "CMake"
  "Major mode for editing CMake source files."
  ...
  )
```

What I want to do is to create a minor mode `ros-mode` which would override the `cmake-indent()` function with my own, but keep everything else the same compared to the original cmake-mode.el. The mode line should show `ROS` when the minor mode is active.

I have no experience with creating minor modes, but I feel like this should be easy for someone with experience. Thank you for helping!

Comment: The key ingredient is this line:  `(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'cmake-indent)` All you need to do is change it to something like `(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'my-cmake-indent)` where your new function is called `my-cmake-indent`.  You don't really need a `minor-mode`, but you can Google that if you want -- you only need that one (1) line of code and change the mode-line lighter to `" ROS"` and you are done.  You can also Google things like:  **setq "indent-line-function" emacs** to see other examples.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Would you mind writing it more fully as an answer, preferably adding a check to make sure that `cmake-mode` is available?

Comment: I have a major project today and was just waiting for the coffee to brew while reading the latest threads.  I'll need to let another forum participant take over from here . . . :)  Your example uses a `major-mode` (which is not what you want) -- you may wish to instead Google for:  **"define-minor-mode" emacs**  And, of course, you want to restore the original value of `indent-line-function` when the `minor-mode` is turned *off*.

Comment: For clarity, are you certain that you want a *minor* mode, rather than a *major* mode derived from `cmake-mode`? In which circumstances would the minor mode be enabled?

Comment: @phils I want a minor mode because I'd like to build on top of it other features later on. If I'm editing a `CMakeLists.txt` file, I want to use `M-x ros-mode` to trigger a set of personal configurations for working with ROS (Robot Operating System)-specific files.

Comment: @lawlist where do I put the `(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'my-cmake-indent)` statement in the minor mode definition?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to automatically detect that you are working with ROS-specific files and invoke a major `ros-mode` in the first place (with all the desired personal configurations) instead of `cmake-mode`? Or even if you have to invoke it manually, wouldn't a major mode still fit the bill? (i.e. would you ever want to *toggle* a minor `ros-mode` on and off again for any given file? It sounds like you would just want it *on* for such files?)

Comment: I'm pushing the point because a derived major mode is the *simplest* solution, if that's all you actually need.

Comment: I recommend working with @phils, as that participant is highly knowledegable.  `(define-minor-mode ros-mode "A minor-mode for working with ROS (Robot Operating System)-specific files." :init-value nil :lighter " ROS" :keymap nil :global nil :group 'cmake (cond (ros-mode (setq-local indent-line-function 'my-cmake-indent) (when (called-interactively-p 'any) (message "Turned ON 'ros-mode'."))) (t (if (eq major-mode 'cmake-mode) (setq-local indent-line-function 'cmake-indent) (kill-local-variable 'indent-line-function)) (when (called-interactively-p 'any) (message "Turned OFF 'ros-mode'.")))))`

Comment: @lawlist I wrote in an answer how I ended up doing it. I would appreciate it though if you would post the above in your own answer, with proper indentation of how the code should look like because that one liner is painful to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going for a derived major mode as suggested by [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils). I wrote in `~/.emacs.d/lisp/ros-cmake-mode.el`:

```
(require 'cmake-mode)

(defun ros-cmake-indent ()
   ;; my code here...
  )

;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode ros-cmake-mode cmake-mode "CMake[ROS]"
  "Major mode for editing ROS CMakeLists.txt files."

  ;; Setup indentation function.
  (set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'ros-cmake-indent))

(provide 'ros-cmake-mode)
```

Then in `~/.emacs.d/lisp/init.el` (using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)):

```
(use-package cmake-mode
  ;; major-mode for editing CMake sources
  :load-path "lisp/"
  :config
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cmake\\'" . cmake-mode))
  (autoload 'cmake-mode "lisp/cmake-mode.el" t))

(use-package ros-cmake-mode
  ;; major-mode for editing CMakeLists.txt files with ROS-style indentation
  :load-path "lisp/"
  :config
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("CMakeLists\\.txt\\'" . ros-cmake-mode))
  (autoload 'ros-cmake-mode "lisp/ros-cmake-mode.el" t))
```

When I open a CMakeLists.txt file, the major mode `CMake[ROS]` is used by default. In case I want to switch to `CMake` major mode (as provided by [cmake-mode.el](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob_plain;hb=master;f=Auxiliary/cmake-mode.el)), I can type `M-x cmake-mode RET`.